# Acknowledging the referee in arXiv preprint

Tags: arxiv, acknowledgement

I am about to submit a paper on arXiv which is accepted but yet to be published. In the accepted version, we have thanked the referee, as their comments helped us in many ways. Should I add this acknowledgement to the arXiv version? Or post without it?

Comment: I assume you don't name them. Why would you omit it?

Comment: Thankyou@Buffy. Actually, I even do not know the reviewer name as it was a single blind review. I just thought it is a common practice or not, Since arxive is not a journal.

Comment: I doubt that it matters to anyone, but I don't see any reason to omit it. Readers understand it is a preprint. But be sure that your publisher permits you to upload a preprint. Some do. Some don't. Some do it themselves.

Comment: My rule: no one ever thinks the worse of someone for *including* thanks; omitting it, maybe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the preprint is the *revised* version that incorporates the changes engendered by the referee comments then I think it would be appropriate to have the acknowledgement.  Contrarily, if the preprint is the *original* version of the paper prior to the revisions then it would not make sense to acknowledge the referee, since they made no contribution to that version of the paper.  (As a more general rule, we add acknowledgements into a paper at the point at which the recipient of the acknowledgement did something to warrant that acknowledgement, so changing revisions of papers may accumulate acknowledgements as people give help.)

Answer (score 7):

Generally, people who read the arXiv version understand that it is a preprint they are reading that may or may not match the published version. So, it matters little whether you include it or exclude it. My preference would be to leave the paper as it is, rather than providing a "different" version explicitly.

But be sure that your publisher permits you to upload a preprint. Some do. Some don't. Some do it themselves.

Comment: Oh I see! do I have to take permission for that? It is a Springer Birkhauser Journal! Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: The policies are probably on their website (the specific journal, not just Springer). Or ask your editor. Even for Springer it may differ by journal.

Comment: @Buffy, agree with you

Comment: Normally, don't bother asking your editors. I wouldn't even bother checking the website, TBH. Updating preprints is such a normal and everyday thing, you don't need to defend yourself from all directions. (When people started posting preprints on the internet in the early 90s, they didn't wait for permissions either.)

Comment: "So, it matters little whether you include it or exclude it." I wouldn't say so. Version confusion is real; many papers are available in 5 different stages of completion on the internet. Any hints about the stage at which a preprint is in are useful.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, for your first comment, note that trouble might arise for a journal that forbids prior publication. Unlikely in your field, I think, but not everywhere.

Comment: @Buffy: This kind of trouble is rare in any field covered by the arXiv. I think there is one Springer journal in my wider field (combinatorics) that forbids AMs on the arXiv, but I've seen my fair share of AMs from that journal on the arXiv, so I wouldn't take that policy too seriously either. Generally, I think the strength of academia.SE is that we can answer questions based on our real-world experience as academics, rather than just quoting the same rules that the OP can find himself.